# DataInputStream UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 88 root cause

Tags: java, apache-poi, utf

I have started seeing this error in my web app app from the past 2 weeks. The server is linux redhat and has had no recent patching. Also it has been up for 44 days. Nor has there been any java or tomcat changes or releases (but the tomcat does get bounced one per day). I know it looks like some sort of charset/locale/encoding issue but I am at a loss now of why it might have started. It ultimately has to do with poi code.

I'm using poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar which pulls in xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar. It seems to be that the error is when xmlbeans initializes and then fails when reading a 2-byte 'modified UTF-8' character from one of its compiled schemas. Thats where I am so far. Why that could start happening in a controlled environment is where I am baffled.

Line of code causing this

```
new SXSSFWorkbook(-1);
```

Some snippets below:

```
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:181)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.<init>(SXSSFWorkbook.java:172)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.<init>(SXSSFWorkbook.java:143)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.<init>(SXSSFWorkbook.java:205)
...
Caused by: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 88
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:634)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$StringPool.readFrom(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:1050)
```

Its not reproducible on local windows machine.

Big thanks for looking and any new ideas.

Comment: What baffles me is why `readUTF()` is being called at all. The `writeUTF()` format is peculiar to Java: it has nothing whatsoever to do with Microsoft POI formats.

Answer (score 0):

It was some sort of corrupt build. Very strange. Anyhow rebuilding worked.